# Databricks Connect: Automatically Accept License Prompt

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, databricks, databricks-connect

I am trying to write a `Dockerfile` that builds a container that leverages Databricks Conenect. So, I need to set-up and install Databricks Connect through Docker `RUN` commands. I have the following:

```
FROM python:3.8
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN apt-get update\
    && apt-get install software-properties-common -y\
    && apt-get update\
    && apt-add-repository "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main"\
    && apt-get update\
    && apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt\
    && databricks-connect configure\
    && databricks-connect test
```

as a simplified example that produces my problem. The step: `databricks-connect configure` prompts for license acceptance with default `N`, and so throws the following error:

```
...
#14 1.345 Do you accept the above agreement? [y/N] Traceback (most recent call last):
#14 1.346   File "/usr/local/bin/databricks-connect", line 8, in <module>
#14 1.346     sys.exit(main())
#14 1.346   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/databricks_connect.py", line 281, in main
#14 1.346     configure()
#14 1.346   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/databricks_connect.py", line 119, in configure
#14 1.346     accept = input().strip()
#14 1.346 EOFError: EOF when reading a line
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c databricks-connect configure]: exit code: 1
```

How can I accept this automatically as part of the Docker build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like this (stolen from [this demo](https://github.com/silviutofan92/databricks-cicd-definitelynotademo/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml#L32)), because besides accepting the license terms, you also need to provide other parameters:

```sh
echo "y
$(databricks_host)
$(databricks_token)
$(cluster_id)
$(org_id)
15001" | databricks-connect configure
```

Or you can just generate `~/.databricks-connect` file that is just JSON:

```json
{
  "host": "https://host",
  "cluster_id": "cluster",
  "org_id": "org_id",
  "port": "15001"
}
```

Comment: Yep! The first option works looking something like the below (for anyone looking in the future):
```text
RUN echo "y\
    $(DATABRICKS_ADDRESS)\
    $(DATABRICKS_API_TOKEN)\
    $(DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID)\
    $(DATABRICKS_ORG_ID)\
    15001" | databricks-connect configure
RUN databricks-connect test
```